# Find the $n$th-term of 0, 1, 1, 2, 2... (each integer is repeated once)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

This question is from Thomas Calculus II. The answer (according to calculus solutions) is supposed to be $$\frac{n-\frac{1}{2}+(-1)^n(\frac{1}{2})}{2} $$

However there isn't any development to get into the answer, any hints to start it?

Comment: Start by getting a formula for the odd-numbered terms and another for the even-numbered terms and then try to merge them.

Comment: You can start with $a_n=\frac{n-1}{2}$ for odd $n$ and $a_n=\frac{n}{2}$ for even $n$. This is easy to see. Now you only need to consider that $(-1)^n\cdot \frac{1}{2}$ oscillates between $-1/2$ and $1/2$

Comment: [This](https://oeis.org/search?q=0%2C1%2C1%2C2%2C2&language=english&go=Search) may help.

Comment: As an aside... the closed form solution is even easier if you are allowed to use floor functions or ceiling functions... it being simply $\left\lceil\frac{n}{2}\right\rceil$ (*where we start with index $0$, adjust as desired if starting from index 1*)

Comment: @Peter I'm not following what you are saying... $a(n)=\left\lceil \frac{n}{2}\right\rceil$ is $a(0)=0, a(1)=1, a(2)=1, a(3)=2,\dots$  On the other hand $b(n)=\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor$ is $b(0)=0, b(1)=0, b(2)=1, b(3)=1,b(4)=2,\dots$  Note the difference between ceilings $\lceil$ and floors $\lfloor$.  In any event, it should have been covered by the "*adjust as desired*" qualifying statement I included.

Comment: @JMoravitz Oops, I thought you used the truncate-function instead of the ceil-function. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model to know is $(-1)^n$ which alternates $1$ and $-1$.

Our sequence is approximately $n/2$, so we merely have to adjust $n/2$ by something related to $(-1)^n$ to get it.  So compute a few terms
$$
\begin{aligned}
n & & a_n & & n/2 & & a_n - n/2\\
1 & & 0 & & 1/2 & & -1/2 \\
2 & & 1 & & 1 & & 0 \\
3 & & 1 & & 3/2 & & -1/2 \\
4 & & 2 & & 2 & & 0 \\
5 & & 2 & & 5/2 & & -1/2 \\
\end{aligned}
$$

To get alternating $-1/2,0,-1/2,0$ do this
$$\begin{aligned}
n & & (-1)^n & & (-1)^n-1 & & ((-1)^n - 1)/4\\
1 & & -1 & & -2 & & -1/2\\
2 & &  1 & & 0 & & 0\\
3 & & -1 & & -2 & & -1/2\\
4 & &  1 & & 0 & & 0\\
5 & & -1 & & -2 & & -1/2\\
6 & &  1 & & 0 & & 0
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Now I can clearly see how $-1^n$ is working in this function. Thanks.